# unable to send json array using jquery-ajax to web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

my web api method not receiving any data through ajax call.
actually i am sending an object array like this:

```
 [{"Id":1,"columnName":"Name","onPage":true,"onReport":false},{"Id":2,"columnName":"Email","onPage":true,"onReport":false},{"Id":3,"columnName":"Password","onPage":false,"onReport":true},{"Id":4,"columnName":"Country","onPage":false,"onReport":true},{"Id":5,"columnName":"State","onPage":false,"onReport":true},{"Id":6,"columnName":"filename","onPage":false,"onReport":false},{"Id":7,"columnName":"Salary","onPage":false,"onReport":false}]

   $(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function () {
    console.log(expressionValue);
    var obj = JSON.stringify(expressionValue);
    console.log(obj );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/test/saveSettings",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: {expressionValue : JSON.stringify(expressionValue)},
        success: function () {
            alert("Settings updated successfully");
        }
    });
});
```

---

Web Api Method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void saveSettings( setting s)
        {

        }
```

My Model looks like this:

```
public class setting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> onPage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> onReport { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's a `dataTye:"JSON",`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function () {
    //console.log(expressionValue);
    //var obj = JSON.stringify(expressionValue);
    //console.log(obj );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("saveSettings","test")",
        data: {s: JSON.stringify(expressionValue)},
        success: function () {
            alert("Settings updated successfully");
        }
    });
});
```